# Retrying to send files by spring integration using ftp:outbound channel

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-retry

I have a working spring batch job with two steps and I want to add a retry logic to ftp sending step.

- First step reads from database and outputs xml files
- The second step send this file to an ftp host using spring integration

The second step is configured as following

```
<step id="sendFileByFtp" next="moveResource">
     <tasklet ref="ftpJobTasklet" />
</step>
<bean id="ftpJobTasklet" class="com...FtpOutboundTasklet" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" ref="ypportal-siparis-outputFile"></property>
    <property name="ftpChannel" ref="ftpOutputChannel"></property>      
</bean>
```

And ftpOutputChannel is configured with a ftpClientFactory utilizing DefaultFtpSessionFactory

```
<int:channel id="ftpOutputChannel"></int:channel>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter session-factory="ftpClientFactory" id="ftpOutbound" channel="ftpOutputChannel" remote-directory="inbox" auto-create-directory="true" temporary-remote-directory="tmp" >
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I want to add retry logic to this second step, which will retry/resume on connection failures to remote ftp host.

Using spring integration 2.2.2 and spring batch 2.1.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`, as described here... http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

There is a sample here...
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more

It shows various configuration for the retry (exponential backoff etc).